# Memoize a curried function

Tags: javascript, caching, memoization, currying

```
const f = (arg1) => (arg2) => { /* returns something */ }
```

Is it possible to memoize f with regard to the 2 arguments, namely:

```
f(1)(2);
f(1)(3); // Cache not hit
f(4)(2); // Cache not hit
f(1)(2); // Cache hit
```

Comment: My guess is you should add a different layer that would cache calls....

Comment: check out the `reselect` library. should do what you want out of the box.

Comment: why does it need to be currified, seems like a needless abstraction.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could take a `Map` as cache and take nested maps for all following arguments.

This cache works for arbitrary count of arguments and reuses the values from the former calls.

It works by taking a curried function and an optional `Map`. If the map is not supplied, a new map is created which serves as base cache for all other calls of the returned closure or the final result.

The inner function takes a single argument and checks if this value is in the map.

- If not, call the curried function and check the returned value

  - if function, create a new closure over the function and a new map,
  - if no function take the result,

  as value for a new element of the map.
- Finally return the value from the map.

```js
const cached = (fn, map = new Map()) => arg => {
    const inCache = map.has(arg);
    const hint = inCache ? 'in cache' : 'not in cache';

    console.log(arg, hint);

    if (!inCache) {
        const value = fn(arg);
        const result = typeof value === 'function' ? cached(value, new Map()) : value;

        map.set(arg, result);
    }

    return map.get(arg);
};

const f = a => b => c => a * b * c; // the original curried function
const g = cached(f); // its cached variant

console.log(g(1)(2)(5)); // not not not 10
console.log(g(1)(3)(4)); //  in not not 12
console.log(g(4)(2)(3)); // not not not 24
console.log(g(1)(2)(6)); //  in  in not 12
console.log(g(4)(2)(3)); //  in  in  in 24
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please, elaborate a little bit more your answer (explanation) It's very difficult to understand how all of that ton of functions works ;)

Comment: @robe007, do you mean `f = ...`? that is a function with one parameter and returns a function with another paramter, and returns the same and then returns the result. basically it's a closure over the parameters.

Comment: Nice! I have used a similar technique here -> https://github.com/tonix-tuft/react-suspense-async-effect

Comment: Nice one again! I just noticed that it can be done with an object `{}` instead of a map (use `.hasOwnProperty(arg)` for existence testing). Is there a particular reason why you used `new Map()` or is one solution as good as the other?

Comment: @cars10m, in maps, the key can be any type, where as objects know only strings and symbols.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the canonical memoization function.

A function that needs to cache its result is given a `cache` function that is used to store and retrieve previous results:

```js
const sum = memo(cache => a => b => cache(`${a}+${b}`, () => a + b));
//               ^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
//               A                        B            C
```

- **A** — The `cache` function is provided by the `memo` function.
  *(A memoized function can opt-out from caching some results if necessary.)*
- **B** — A unique key for the result. (e.g. `cache['1+2'] = 3`)
- **C** — A *thunk* that returns the result.
  *(So we can check if we have it already before computing it.)*

This supports both curried and non-curried functions but also functions that return a function as a value.

The `memo` function can be implemented as follow:

```js
const memo = fn => {
  const ns = Symbol();
  const cache = (key, thunk) => cache[ns][key] ??= thunk();
  cache[ns] = {};
  return fn(cache);
};
```

I quite like the [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) operator for managing the cache:

```js
a ??= answer()
```

The expression on the right is evaluated and assigned to `a` **if and only if** `a` is not already defined. Then it returns the value of `a`:

```js
const answer = () => (console.log('returning the answer'), 42);

let a;

a ??= answer();
//=> LOG: returning the answer
//=> 42

a ??= answer();
//=> 42

a ??= 40;
//=> 42
```

I've used a symbol to hide the actual cache set on the `cache` function. A symbol is not returned when enumerating properties of an object:

```js
const foo = {};
const key1 = Symbol();
const key2 = 'bar';

foo[key1] = 42;
foo[key2] = 41;

Object.keys(foo);
//=> ['bar']

Object.entries(foo);
//=> [['bar', 41]]
```

**Demo**

```js
// curried memoized function
const sum = memo(cache => a => b =>
  cache(`${a}+${b}`,
    () => (console.log(`computing ${a}+${b}…`), a+b)));
  
console.log(sum(1)(2));
console.log(sum(1)(2));
console.log(sum(1)(2));

// non-curried memoized function
const mul = memo(cache => (a, b) =>
  cache(`${a}*${b}`,
    () => (console.log(`computing ${a}*${b}…`), a*b)));
  
console.log(mul(2, 3));
console.log(mul(2, 3));
console.log(mul(2, 3));

// function-returning function
const deferred_sum = memo(cache => a => b =>
  cache(`${a}+${b}`,
    () => (console.log(`defer computing ${a}+${b}…`), () => a+b)));
    
console.log(deferred_sum(1)(2)());
console.log(deferred_sum(1)(2)());
console.log(deferred_sum(1)(2)());
```

```html
<script>
const memo = fn => {
  const ns = Symbol();
  const cache = (key, thunk) => cache[ns][key] ??= thunk();
  cache[ns] = {};
  return fn(cache);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question — you could have independent caches for each function. The cache on the outside function will hold functions. Each inside function could get its own independent cache. So calling `f(10)(1)` followed by `f(10)(2)` would result in calling a cached version of the inside function. Calling `f(10)(1)` again would hit both caches:

```js
function getCachedF() {
  // outer cache holds functions keyed to argument
  let outer_memo = {}  
                
  const f = (arg1) => {
    if (!outer_memo.hasOwnProperty(arg1)) {
      // Create inner function on outer cache
      // each inner function needs its own cache
      // because it will return different values
      // given different outer function calls
      let inner_memo = {}                  
      console.log("outer cache miss")
      
      outer_memo[arg1] = (arg2) => {
        // just a normal memoized function
        // cache is simple key:value pair
        if (!inner_memo.hasOwnProperty(arg2)) {
          console.log("inner cache miss")
          inner_memo[arg2] = arg1 + arg2
        }
        return inner_memo[arg2]
      }
    }
    return outer_memo[arg1]
  }
  return f
}

let f = getCachedF()
// both caches miss
console.log("3+5", f(3)(5))

// cached result
console.log("3+5", f(3)(5))

// only inside cache hit
console.log("3+8", f(3)(8))

// inside cache only hits if both args are the same
console.log("10+8", f(10)(8))
```

Another alternative would be to have single cache with keys that are a combination of both arguments, but then the inner function would always have to be called.

Answer (score -1):

You can not to pass map to every function. 
You can do like the next:

```js
const memoize = fn => {
  const cache = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const curriedFn = fn(...args);
    return (...next) => {
      const key = // generate your key
      if (key in cache) return cache[key];
      return (cache[key] = curriedFn(...next));
    }
  }
}
```