# How to "remember" previously calculated values in an expensive recursive function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, react-hooks

Suppose I have a recursive callback such as this (but more complex):

```
const weightedFactorial = useCallback(n => {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  return weight * n * weightedFactorial(n - 1);
},[weight]);
```

Is there a way to store previously calculated values, such that if the function is called on a repeated index, it is possible to skip the recursion?

```
const value1 = weightedFactorial(60) 
// Calculate recursively

const value2 = weightedFactorial(30) 
// This value should already be known 
// and the calculation should be skipped
```

I've tried to keep a state with known values but I seem to get stuck in a loop, probably because it needs to be a dependency of the callback,

```
const [knownValues, setKnownValues] = useState([{ n: 0, value: 1 }]);
const weightedFactorial = useCallback(n => {
  const known = knownValues.find(known => known.n === n);
  if (known?.value) {
    return known.value;
  }

  const newValue = weight * n * weightedFactorial(n - 1);
  setKnownValues(knownValues => [...knownValues, { n, value: newValue }]);
  return newValue;
},[knownValues, weight]);
```

Comment: Don't use a state. Use a ref. And make it either a simple array or a `Map` in which you can lookup by index.

Comment: Doesn't look like a good use case for `useCallback()` (because, it is not guaranteed that all previously _remembered_ values are still accessible, in the first place). That rather seems to be a dynamic programming task, but there's no way to suggest some meaningful solution without seeing your actual callback.

Comment: @Bergi - Thank you, this is exactly the hint I needed. I also had to add a useEffect to reset the map when some of the dependencies change, but it is working perfectly. Feel free to submit an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - That seems to be why my sample code didn't work, but it is possible with a ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to store results for [memoisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a `Map`, or an array if your function parameter is a positive integer:

```
function FactorialExamples(props) {
  const results = [1];
  const factorial = n => {
    if (n in results) return results[n]; // also takes care of our base case n==0
    return results[n] = n * factorial(n-1);
  };
  
  return <p>
    5!: { factorial(5) }
    <br />
    10!: { factorial(10) }
  </p>;
}
```

This will work nicely and not compute factorials more than once if you call `factorial` multiple times. However, it will still redo the computation on every rendering of your function component. To persist the results across re-renders, move the `results` variable out of the function into the module scope, or put it inside a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) (that will be stored once per mounted component):

```
function Factorial(props) {
  const results = useRef([1]).current;

  const factorial = n => {
    if (n in results) return results[n];
    return results[n] = n * factorial(n-1);
  };

  return <p>
    {props.n}!: { factorial(props.n) }
  </p>;
}

function Demo() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  return <div>
    <input type="number" value={value} onInput=(e => setValue(e.currentTarget.valueAsNumber)} min="0" />
    <Factorial n={value} />
  </div>;
}
```

But you have a more complicated case: the `weightedFactorial` also depends on a `weight` state, not just on its argument<sup>1</sup>. You could reset the reference every time the `weight` changes, but that's complicated and error-prone.

Instead, use an approach similar to your `useCallback`, that switches out the results store together with the "callback". Instead of `useCallback`, use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and return a closure from it:

```
const weightedFactorial = useMemo(() => {
  const results = [1];
  return n => {
    if (n in results) return results[n]; 
    return weight * n * weightedFactorial(n - 1);
  };
}, [weight]);
```

<sub>1: Of course, you could just treat both `weight` and `n` as arguments, and use [a standard approach for memoising functions with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54077182/1048572) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61402804/1048572)). Then the results could again be stored statically or in a reference.</sub>

Comment: Wonderfully written, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.useMemo` to calculate the value on the first render or when a dependency changes. But maybe you are referring to `memoization` so that a previously calculate value doesn't need other computation.
https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/memoize or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-understanding-recursion

You can combine both `useMemo` and `memoization` to achieve what you need.

Comment: That is not quite what I meant, I need to store the intermediate steps in a recursive function so that subsequent calls to that function don't need to go through the recursion and can simply be looked up. I ended up using a react ref btw

Comment: This is exactly what a memoized functions does. It store in its internale cache all the intermediate calculations and when you call it again if found the already calculated value in the cache.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You are completely correct